# Is it possible to download only one part of a file (e.g, the first 100KB) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm just curious about whether this is possible - I know how to download a file, but how can I download only the first 100KB of a file?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a byte-range request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
        string GetWebPageContent(string url)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            HttpWebRequest request;
            const int bytesToGet = 1000;
            request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

//get first 1000 bytes
            request.AddRange(0, bytesToGet - 1);

// the following code is alternative, you may implement the function after your needs
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Stolen from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/ce0e2e13-ec2c-468f-beea-469acb2468fd).